# How can I use my own build of a package with stack?

Tags: haskell, sdl-2, haskell-stack

The bigger picture is that I'm trying to use the `sdl2` package from Stackage (lts 8.1). Though, I'm having a bit of an issue; The package is missing a compiler flag, as detailed in [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/haskell-game/sdl2/issues/139). As such, it doesn't build properly.

However, if I clone the repository, I can add the missing compiler flag to the .cabal file and build it myself, which solves the issue. I now have a working build of the package.

So my question is: How can I, in a separate project, use my own working build of the `sdl2` package, instead of the one from Stackage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing that with Stack. The one I like the most, and which sounds like a good fit for your scenario, is uploading the repository with your fork to GitHub (or wherever else you find appropriate) and then adding a reference to the online repository as an `extra-dep` to the [`packages` section](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#packages) of `stack.yaml`. For the sake of illustration, here is the `packages` section for a project of mine in which I had to do that:

```yaml
packages:
- '.'
- location:
    git: https://github.com/duplode/threepenny-gui
    commit: 7e4e3a41cbb5e55312d4375612790d633ccf1e7a
  extra-dep: true
```